# Can I use multiple @hostlistener or events based on browser?

Tags: angular, events

I'm using @hostlistener in Angular7 directive. Can I use more than one event on this?

Problem is that listening for the 'keydown' event is fine on anything but Android as the latter has no key events.

Switching to 'input' event solves this problem but doesn't cover Firefox (and probably Edge) as there's no 'inputType' (and other things) on the latter which causes the actual input field to allow any input.

So my goal is to be able to use 'keydown' for Firefox and Edge and use 'input' for anything else. Is that possible?

Used 'keydown', 'keypress' and 'input' events

```
    @HostListener('input', ['$event'])
    onInput(event: any) {
        this.parseKeyDown(event);
    }
```

```
    parseKeyDown(event: any) {
        if (event.inputType === 'deleteContentBackward' || event.inputType === 'deleteContentForward') {
            let str = this.ngModel.substr(0, this.ngModel.length - 1);
            if (str.length === 0) {
                str = '0';
            }
            // handle 'str'
        }
...
        if (e.inputType === 'insertText' && e.data.match(this.regex)) {
            // handle ngModel
        }
    }
```

Code shortened for readability.

This works in anything but Firefox/Edge where pressing backspace or delete keys deletes the last char. In Firefox the field just falls back to a text field, allows any GUI input and doesn't update ngModel.

Since there's no 'inputType' in Firefox nothing happens.

---

EDIT My solution

```
    @HostListener('keydown', ['$event'])
    @HostListener('input', ['$event'])
    onInput(e: any) {
        this.parseKeyDown(e);
    }

    parseKeyDown(e: any) {
        const key = e.key;
        if (key) { // Browsers WITH key events
...
        } else { // Browsers WITHOUT key events
            const data = e.data;
            const inputType = e.inputType;
...
```

Comment: You could make use of event `change`

Comment: Thanks but event 'change' only fires onBlur. I need to handle each individual input as it happens

Comment: If I understand you right you want to implement something like custom input element with corresponding handlers and GUI (maybe) and need to listen for changes. If I'm right then you should look at Custom Form Controls where you can control value changes and `change` propagation etc.

Answer (score 58, accepted):

With `@hostlistener` you can listen to single event with a single decorator. If you want to listen for multiple events you can add multiple `@hostlistener` to a single function e.g

```
@HostListener('click', ['$event'])
@HostListener('mouseover', ['$event'])
onEvent(event) {
    console.log(event)
}
```

If it's not desirable you can hook into Angular Event Manager Plugin and customize it. Here is an [article](https://netbasal.com/lifting-the-veil-insights-into-angulars-eventmanagerplugin-ed9d14cbb31a) show this.

Comment: Thanks alt255 the 'double' hostlistener was what I was after.

Turns out you cannot decide which hostlistener to use though as only the first fired hostlistener goes to the method. So when I use
```
    @HostListener('keydown', ['$event'])
    @HostListener('input', ['$event'])
    onInput(e: any) {
        this.parseKeyDown(e);
    }
```
and there's a 'keydown' event the 'input' event never fires.

Comment: @JohanFaerch I am facing the same problem. did you find any solution or any alternative for this

Comment: @pankajmalik I have added my solution to the initial question.

Comment: If you generally have a common function, but do need to make certain distinctions within: `switch(event.type) {...`